# Which AWS services and specs should I best use for a file sharing web system?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm building a web system where 100-150 users will keep uploading/downloading ~10 GB total worth of audio files everyday (average of 150 total uploads and 250 total downloads per day).

I'm still trying to read about the whole AWS ecosystem and I need help with the ff:

1. For file storage, should I use S3 or EBS volumes mounted to an EC2 instance? From what I read, S3 is much cheaper and more scalable than EBS, but it's also slower. Is the speed difference really that huge or noticable for my use case? What are the advantages of a mounted EBS volume vs. S3?
2. What would be the best EC2 instance type for my use case? (i.e. frequent uploads and downloads) Will the General Purpose ones (T2, M4 etc) be enough to handle that load? (see above)

I can provide more info on my requirements/use cases if needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Start with S3.** S3 is a web api for putting and retrieving *huge* amounts of data, whereas EBS would be an NFS-mounted device. S3 will be more scalable from a data warehousing perspective, and in terms of access from multiple concurrent instances (should you do that, in the future.) Only use EBS if you actually need a filesystem for some reason. It doesn't sound like you do.

From there, you can look into some data archiving if you end up having huge amounts of data that doesn't need to be regularly available, to save some money.

**Yes, use a t2 to start.** Though, you should design your system so that it doesn't really matter, and you can easily teardown/replace instances. Using S3 helps with that pattern. You still need to figure out how you will deploy and configure your application to newly launched instances, though. You should /assume/ that your instance will go down, disappear, etc. So, you should be able to failover to another one on demand.